# How to move files if directory is not empty?

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to move files from a directory if it is not empty. This script is added in `cronjob` but it is always executing regardless of files are present or not? What is wrong in this thing?

```
#!/bin/bash
logFolder="/dstDir/`date '+%Y-%m-%d/%H-%M'`"
tempLogFolder="sourceDir"   
if [ -z "$(ls -A $tempLogFolder | grep *.log)" ]; then
    mkdir -p $logFolder
    mv $tempLogFolder/*.log $logFolder/
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) You don't need any external commands to count files in a directory. The shell can do it itself.

Try creating a helper function that checks how many arguments are passed to it. Then have the shell expand the glob `"$tempLogFolder"/*.log`. No need for `ls` or `grep`. The only trick is enabling the `nullglob` option so if no files exist the glob expands to nothing.

```
files_exist() { (($# > 0)); }
shopt -s nullglob

if files_exist "$tempLogFolder"/*.log; then
    mkdir -p "$logFolder"
    mv "$tempLogFolder"/*.log "$logFolder"/
fi
```

Comment: It is working if I run it manually  but doesnot work from cronjob

Answer (score -1):

- grep accepts regex, not glob. If you want to use glob like `*.log` you put it in your `ls` something like `ls .... *.log` (using ls output is not 100% safe).
- If you want to use grep, please use regex, I guess what you meant is `\.log$`.
- If you want to check if grep has found matches, you should check the return code (`$?`) of `grep`, instead of using `-z` test.
- If you put it in crontab, the script will always be executed.

Comment: you mean the script will always execute regardless of the truth statement?

Comment: @MaheshUligade your if check is just a statement of your script. your script will be executed but if it is gonna move your files, you control it. (by the if)

Answer (score -1):

I think you want,

```
if [ -n "$(ls -A $tempLogFolder | grep *.log)" ]; then
    ...
```

because you are only interested in whether the string returned has a non-zero length.

Comment: @Kent Ok, how do you think I could improve it?